# Java exceptions with same name - which one is it?

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace

Is there a general way of figuring out which exception to catch when there are multiple exceptions with the same name? This has happened to me with HttpException, where there are four different ones on my build path. As far as I see it, the stack trace doesn't give away the package name.

```
[...]
Caused by: HttpException: 404 File not found
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.execCommon(HttpQuery.java:446)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.execGet(HttpQuery.java:289)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.exec(HttpQuery.java:240)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execSelect(QueryEngineHTTP.java:302)
[...]
```

Comment: I guess you could catch `Exception`, print the fully package-qualified name of the exception class, and then rethrow it, if there isn't a better way. You might also try looking at where the exception comes from and checking the documentation to see what exceptions that method might throw.

Comment: I guess the Exception may be same but the message with the exception matters, don't you think in this case its showing 404 but the message shows a file that is needed is not found.

Comment: @pathfinder2104 To provide additional context: It is not really a file missing but an online problem that happens sporadically which requires me to Thread.sleep for a while so I need to catch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consult the API, or the documentation. The Javadoc for Jena declares that [`HttpQuery.exec`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/sparql/engine/http/HttpQuery.html#exec%28%29) throws [`QueryExceptionHTTP`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/sparql/engine/http/QueryExceptionHTTP.html), which has a fully-qualified name of `com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryExceptionHTTP`.

Comment: That's not it, I got a `HttpException`, not a `QueryExceptionHttp`.

Comment: No, you got a `QueryExceptionHTTP` which, in [its `toString` method](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/6bdbe8d3248f235cbee70046915d361e414b5a6b/jena-arq/src/main/java/com/hp/hpl/jena/sparql/engine/http/QueryExceptionHTTP.java#L96) prepends `"HttpException: "`.

Comment: If that's true then it's really confusing. I always thought after "Caused by:" comes the exception class name...